# Xcode: После удаления Cocoa Pods возникает ошибка Missing file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa

После удаления Cocoa Pods при компиляции возникает ошибка Missing file. Подскажите что сделать, чтобы убрать эти предупреждения. 
В качестве примера использовал этот пример - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто: просто нужно закомитить и открыть проект заново!

Эти предупреждения не являются предупреждениями по факту, они сообщают о вашем состоянии репозитория SVN. Это правильно, что каталоги не показаны, ведь их больше не существует, `CocoaPods` сохраняет заголовки в систему `Pods/Headers/{Private, Public}`.

Вы должны обновить вашу рабочую копию, чтобы отразить эти изменения.

- *Вариант 1*: Cделать новый коммит.
- *Вариант 2*: Вспользоваться терминалом

  ```
  svn upgrade
  ```